# Try Catch logic error with file i/o in Java

Tags: java, file-io, error-handling, try-catch

So, I've been trying to learn java from various sources, I've been learning for about 2 years now. So far everything has been going smoothly, i haven't had to post on stackoverflow for a while. Recently I've been trying to figure out how to create and read files with java. I can do both of those things in separate apps, but when i try to do both it doesn't always work.

What i want to happen:
I want my program to create `data.txt`, then I want it to read the data and produce an error log on `error.txt`.

What happens:
The data.txt file gets created as expected, but nothing is written to the error.txt file. I'm having trouble grasping the try/catch block and how exactly it works. Anyone got any ideas? even just some advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class dataReader {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File fileName;
        fileName = new File("data.txt");
        PrintWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileName);

        File errorFile;
        errorFile = new File("errors.txt");
        PrintWriter outputErrorFile;
        outputErrorFile = new PrintWriter(errorFile);

        Scanner inputFile;



        int recordNumber = 0;


        String inputData;



        outputFile.println(77);
        outputFile.println("Fred");
        outputFile.println(92);
        outputFile.println("Wilma");
        outputFile.println(89.9);
        outputFile.println("Barney");
        outputFile.println(42);
        outputFile.println("BettyS");

        inputFile = new Scanner(fileName);

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {

            recordNumber++;

            try {
                inputData = inputFile.nextLine();
                if (Integer.parseInt(inputData) < 50) {

                    outputErrorFile.println(recordNumber + ", " + inputData + ", is less than 50.");
                } else if (Integer.parseInt(inputData) > 90) {
                    outputErrorFile.println(recordNumber + ", " + inputData + ", is less than 50.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                outputErrorFile.println(recordNumber + ",  That's not an integer.");
            }

        }



        outputFile.close();
        outputErrorFile.close();


        System.out.println("Program terminated.");

    }
}
```

Comment: What you are expecting to do

Comment: Please provide the content of your data.txt. At least several lines.

Comment: @TagirValeev it seems data.txt was written first and the op tries to read that after ?

Comment: Ah I see. Then he simply should close it *before* reopening for reading.

Comment: @Stan Harris your code works as you expected ? when I run your code, you have some context inside your error log.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `outputFile.close();` line before `inputFile = new Scanner(fileName);`. Currently it's just cached in the memory and not written actually to the disk.

Comment: the error.txt has some content inside it; I do not know whether if they are right or not but it seem they are right. so the op is ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) says it all. The PrintWriter(Writer) constructor creates a writer which is not automatically flushed.

You have to call close or flush method to write your data to the file.

So you have to use `outputFile.close();` method before starting reading.

and as a good practice you have to close all your `PrintWriter` instances to avoid memory leak.

just in this case please add `inputFile.close();` at the end of your program.